# object from List in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call a value out from my List and it looks like this:

```
[{
    "gesundheitsamtId": 16,
    "name": "Stadt Dortmund",
    "telefonenummer": "0231 50-23606",
    "email": "gesundheitsamt@dortmund.de",
    "adresse": [{
        "adresseId": 16,
        "strasse": "Hövelstr.",
        "hausnr": "8",
        "ort": "Dortmund",
        "plz": "44137"
    }]
}, {
    "gesundheitsamtId": 70,
    "name": "Stadt Dortmund",
    "telefonenummer": "0231 50-23606",
    "email": "gesundheitsamt@dortmund.de",
    "adresse": [{
        "adresseId": 70,
        "strasse": "Hövelstr.",
        "hausnr": "8",
        "ort": "Dortmund",
        "plz": "44137"
    }]
}]
```

I tried this

```
var obj = ['adresse'][0].ort;
```

but it said

> UndefinedType

Comment: Please spend [more time researching your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418) before asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
    "gesundheitsamtId": 16,
    "name": "Stadt Dortmund",
    "telefonenummer": "0231 50-23606",
    "email": "gesundheitsamt@dortmund.de",
    "adresse": [{
        "adresseId": 16,
        "strasse": "Hövelstr.",
        "hausnr": "8",
        "ort": "Dortmund",
        "plz": "44137"
    }]
}, {
    "gesundheitsamtId": 70,
    "name": "Stadt Dortmund",
    "telefonenummer": "0231 50-23606",
    "email": "gesundheitsamt@dortmund.de",
    "adresse": [{
        "adresseId": 70,
        "strasse": "Hövelstr.",
        "hausnr": "8",
        "ort": "Dortmund",
        "plz": "44137"
    }]
}]

console.log(data[0].adresse[0].ort);
```